# Launch ASP Development Server Manually?

Tags: asp.net, webdev.webserver

There has to be a way to do this, I was googling information but I can't seem to get it to work.  The sites I checked out said to do something along the lines of

**`start /B %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\webdev.webserver.exe /path:"D:\MyFolder" /vpath:/HelloWorldWebSite`**

In a batch file.  However, none of my framework folders (im developing in 3.5) have this **`webdev.webserver.exe`** file.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:  Thanks to Casper over on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57094/how-can-i-programmatically-run-the-aspnet-development-server-using-c#57105), I found where the file resides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0

got it here on my pc

used task manager to track it