# Does Cassini DevServer support Integrated Pipeline mode?

Tags: cassini-dev

This is something I did not manage to find from the internet.

We have a web application that uses SignalR that requires Owin that needs IIS Integrated Pipeline mode. When I am running our web application on Cassini Dev Server I get following error:

```
[PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.]
   System.Web.HttpResponse.get_Headers() +214
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders..ctor(HttpResponseBase response) +37
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.CreateEnvironment() +492
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.GetInitialEnvironment(HttpApplication application) +263
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.PrepareInitialContext(HttpApplication application) +19
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extradata) +462
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +556
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Running IIS Express and other alternatives in automatic tests is PITA.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-pipeline-mode-in-iis7  Basically, this could require re-writing cassini to integrate directly with ASP.Net (just like IIS does) instead of treating it as external component.

Comment: This is quite weird. Now, all of sudden, devserver works with my site.

Comment: Perhaps your web.config or other configuration options changed for either the website or SignalR or Owin?

Comment: Having the same problem, Do you know how you were able to get this to work?

Comment: Had the same issue - I solved it by downloading the owin/signalR projects from github/codeplex and commented-out 2-3 code lines. seems to work fine now

Comment: Having the same problem -- using Cassinidev so that Selenium can hit the build server externally (IIS Express does NOT allow this!), just ran into adding something that required OWIN and OWIN is killing all of our Selenium tests...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CassiniDev does not support Integrated Pipeline Mode. If you're coming across this error you may want to switch to IISExpress. I did that by using the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20494039/450913).