# Automatically start ASP.MVC project when running test project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selenium, end-to-end

I'm trying to set up a test project for my ASP website. For some tests I want to use selenium to perform end-to-end tests.

Therefor my website has to be running so the tests can access the site.

How can I start my website project when I run tests?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have this registered with IIS and you want to start it locally with the IIS express in the compiler?

Comment: @mutt Thats right. I have a web project and a test project in my solution. I want to start the web project to start in Visual Studio via IIS Express when the tests run.

Answer (score 5):

Please reference the following links.  I believe it is possible, but will be a little tricky.  These are detailed and provide information on doing this programmatically.

[Starting and stopping IIS Express programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772092/starting-and-stopping-iis-express-programmatically)

https://www.reimers.dk/jacob-reimers-blog/testing-your-web-application-with-iis-express-and-unit-tests

- The idea is that you would need to start it and navigate to your particular local app in your browser.
- Then you will need to get the window handle of the open browser window
- Then instantiate your Driver object and use the window handle for that instantiation to get Selenium to execute on the open window.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll see if this works for me.