# Selenium test log.Info not visible

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, logging, visual-studio-2015

I am writing a selenium project with test cases, here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963598/visual-studio-selenium-test-starting-local-project) to my earlier post about it for further information. Here's my project structure:

```
SeleniumTestSuite
+-- Properties
+-- References
+-- Pages
|   +-- BasePage.cs
+-- App.config
+-- HomePageTest.cs
+-- packages.config
```

I am using common-logging for my logging implementation. Here's the code inside of `BasePage.cs`

```
using Common.Logging;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SeleniumTestSuite.pages
{
    class BasePage
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("BasePage");
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private By banner = By.ClassName("banner");

        public BasePage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver = driver;
        }

        public bool isBannerVisible()
        {
            log.Info("Testing default page body");
            return driver.FindElement(banner).Displayed;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run my test case:

```
public void testBasePage()
{
    basePage = new BasePage(driver);
    Assert.IsTrue(basePage.isBannerVisible());
}
```

I just get the following in the output window:

```
------ Discover test started ------
========== Discover test finished: 1 found (0:00:00.1990199) ==========
------ Run test started ------
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:07.3237323) ==========
```

I don't see any of the log information. Here's my `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging">
        <arg key="level" value="INFO" />
        <arg key="showLogName" value="true" />
        <arg key="showDateTime" value="true" />
        <arg key="dateTimeFormat" value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
</configuration>
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Do you have Common.Logging library installed in GAC? If yes, then you need to specify the fully qualified name of the assembly including Version,PublicKeyToken, etc

Comment: Have you tried `log.Debug` instead of `log.Info`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've Selenium tests running from my test assembly using XUnit, it's fairly simple to output data:

https://xunit.github.io/docs/capturing-output.html

At the end, I've the full logs attached to the test cases on Visual Studio Online